# Message queue C++ with Qt for network transmission

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing a new message queue for network messages that a server would send for file copying.

After reading from the socket a defined number of bytes I would emit a signal for interpreting the header, if it can't be interpreted read some more and again emit the signal until there is known type.

After interpreting the header, I have to emit the call to the respective worker(class) to decode the rest of the message.

My question here is, would it be better to use a design pattern with this if yes what would be the best approach or should I do it the old way with a switch?

I'm using Qt 4.8.5 and it should work on all systems (Win/Mac/Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know in advance all your header types then you can use a [`QHash`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qhash.html) to store all your message parsers, mapped to message header types.

So, you need an enum to define all message header types and a base class for all message parsers.
You would end up with:

```
QHash<MessageType, AbstractMessageParser*> mappings;
```

You can then retrieve with a one-liner the parser corresponding to a specific header type.
Of course, all parsers need to be registered in the hash in advance of the actual parsing. I would do it in the initialization phase of your program.

<strike>So, no specific pattern. I suppose you could use the factory pattern, but you'd still end up with a big ass switch.</strike>

You can look at this as either a variation of the [Factory pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) or a variation of the [Service Locator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648968.aspx) pattern.

Comment: You're describing some kind of factory, so there is a pattern after all, see http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html

Comment: @stefaanv: Yes, of course. There is a pattern in everything :). I guess we should call this a static factory.

Comment: @stefaanv: You can also call this service locator.

Answer (score 0):

About using a design pattern or a switch case for handling action in a working thread, I would advice the [command pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html), so you combine the needed information in a command class and then call the class from the working thread.  The problems with a switch case are possibly a huge function and split up of enum/struct/code for each message.